# How can I find this code block's execution time t(n) and big O notation?

Tags: big-o-notation, loops

Hello I am a CSE student and this question was in my homework.

```
double fact(long i)
{
if (i==1 || i==0) return i;
else return i*fact(i-1);
}

funcQ2()
{
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
sum=sum+log(fact(i));
}
```

I thought it is O(n^2) but can the bottom function's log function call make it O(n^3)? I am not sure

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fact(n)` runs at $O(n)$.

So, each iteration of `funcQ2` runs at $O(i)$, assuming `log` runs at constant time.
(There are several algorithms to calculate the log)

Then the question turns into calculating $\sum_{i=1}^n O(i)$, and the answer is $O(n^2)$.

Now suppose your `log(n)` runs at time $O(f(n))$.

Then the answer to your question should be $\sum_{i=1}^n O(f(i))$.
You should calculate that on your own as I don't know the $f$.